# List does not grow or cannot add new element to a list in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

I have created a custom type `Food` which has 4 attributes `name`, `weight`, `fat`, and `calorie`. The web application will get `name` and `weight` from users and calculate the `fat` and `calorie`.

I have an `Add` button to click in order to add a choice to a list.

My problem is when I display the message box to check the list, it always show `1`, no matter how many you have added. Can anyone point out where I am wrong?

P/S: I tried to display the message box before I add an item to a list and it shows `0` <-- this is true.

```
    List<Food> foodList = new List<Food>();
    Food temp = new Food();

    public void addButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      //Get weight value from a textbox
        temp.weight = Convert.ToDouble(weightTextBox.Text);
      //Get name from a provided dropdownlist
        temp.name = DropDownList1.Text;
      //Add to list
        foodList.Add(temp);
      //Check the number of elements in the list
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + foodList.Count + "');", true);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time your page is instantiated, it has an empty `foodList` to which you add exactly one item in `addButton_Click`. And a new instance of the page is created to handle each request from the browser, such as request caused by `addButton` click. You have to implement server-side storage of added items and load them into `foodList` every time.

Comment: So whenever I click Add Button, the page is refresh and it creates a new empty List again?

Comment: yes, it is a new page instance with new empty `foodList` every time.

Comment: I figured out how to keep the `foodList` not be recreated. I used `static List<Food> foodList = new List<Food>();` and now the `foodList.Count` grows. Is this alright?

Comment: No, putting `static` in front of a class member does not fix things. With `static`, `foodList` becomes shared by all requests (processed in parallel by different threads) from different users. Unless you add locking to ensure thread-safety, you are bound to get very hard-to-debug errors in a multi-user environment. Even with that, the content of the `foodList` will be gone once the server-side process is recycled.

Comment: you can use ViewState for this purpose: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31344/Beginner-s-Guide-To-View-State

Answer (score 0):

You should move your `temp` object creation into `addButton_Click`. Like this:

```
List<Food> foodList = new List<Food>();

public void addButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Food temp = new Food();
  //Get weight value from a textbox
    temp.weight = Convert.ToDouble(weightTextBox.Text);
  //Get name from a provided dropdownlist
    temp.name = DropDownList1.Text;
  //Add to list
    foodList.Add(temp);
  //Check the number of elements in the list
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + foodList.Count + "');", true);
}
```

Else you're adding the same object all the time.

Comment: This is not the problem, I tried and it is the same

Comment: @Hien Tran I agreed, this is not a solution of your problem. The correct solution was proposed in other answer here. But leaving "temp" outside of addButton_Click will produce another bug in your app. When you will enter something in your textbox, click "add", enter something else in textbox and click "add" again - your list will contain two copy or your last enter because you doesn't create new object when inserting in list, but change previously added.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev - this is misleading and incorrect. In OP's code `temp` is a page class member, that is created anew together with the page on every request. Therefore, the same reference added to the list twice on two successive `addButton` clicks is not possible.